# Let $M$ be a manifold noncompact. Then there is a closed embebdding of the half line $[0, \infty)$ into $M$.

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold connected hausdorf noncompact. Then there is a closed embebdding of the half line $[0,  \infty)$ into $M$.

I'm hard to build such a function without self-intersections.

Book: Differential Topology, Hirsch. p 27.

Comment: **An Idea:** Let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be an open cover without any finite subcover. Then, you intersect these open sets with your charts, and construct the embedding locally (i.e. if $V$ is a chart, you map $U_\alpha \cap V$ to $W\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and extend).